# How to implement the default web browser in to a JFrame?

Tags: java, browser, dll, jxbrowser

I would like to implement the default browser of a computer in to a Java JFrame. I've took a look at JXBrowser but it costs money. Is there a way to do this? It's fine if additional libraries are required, as long as it is free and working. Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894903/adding-a-web-browser-in-a-jframe-jpanel-jcomponent-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454652/embed-browser-in-java-based-desktop-application

Comment: they are both not duplicates... OP is asking specifically about the system's default browser, not a fixed implementation specific to a library